# Why is a specific import not working in a worker thread?

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

I have a worker thread that successfully imports a lot of files using a pattern (TypeORM models, if relevant). Each of those files in return imports other files - each other and unrelated. That has worked fine for a long time. However, I had to add a new import to many of those files and this one is always `undefined`. It works fine when the app runs normally, but it doesn't import in a worker.

I didn't set up the workers and the devs that did are long gone. I don't know enough about them except the general idea. Why would only one certain import not work while everything else is fine?

The only solution I have for now is detecting whether it's a worker process and skipping this import. It can work, but it's tedious. And I can't even abstract it since it would require putting it in a separate file, which needs to be imported...

Maybe helpful details:

Node version: v16.15.0
System: Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL
Originally written in Typescript, transpiled on runtime using NestJS' built in transpiler. It looks like it uses Webpack under the hood, but I can't be sure.

Comment: There's not much usable information here to help. Node version, build process(es), etc. may all matter.

Comment: @DaveNewton good point. I got pretty confused there with the workers, but you're right, those are basics lol